# pass JSON to underscore via backbone

Tags: json, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm stuck with underscore and backbone. I'm somehow not able to render the JSON within the underscore template. The browser outputs nothing, but there are no error messages. Heres my work:

The server returns the following json:

```
[{"id":"1","vorname":"Magnus","nachname":"R.","geb":"0","natio":""},{"id":"2","vorname":"Konstantin","nachname":"W.","geb":"0","natio":""}]
```

///////My Model://////

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
], function(_, Backbone){

  var MitarbeiterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
  return MitarbeiterModel;
});
```

/////My Collection:///////

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/mitarbeiter',


], function(_, Backbone, MitarbeiterModel){

  var MitarbeiterCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MitarbeiterModel,
    url: '/aquilamus/server/request.php',

  });

  return MitarbeiterCollection;
});
```

//////My View///////

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/mitarbeiter',
  'text!/aquilamus/templates/mitarbeiter/mitarbeiter.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, MitarbeiterCollection, MitarbeiterTemplate){



 var MitarbeiterListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#container"),
    initialize: function(){
      this.collection = new MitarbeiterCollection;

      var newtemplate = MitarbeiterTemplate;
       _.templateSettings.variable = "rc";
      this.template = _.template($(newtemplate).html());
    },
    render: function(){
      var self = this;

      // show some loading message
      this.$el.html('Loading');

      // fetch, when that is done, replace 'Loading' with content
      this.collection.fetch().done(function(){
          console.log(self.collection.toJSON());
          var renderedContent = self.template(self.collection.toJSON());

          self.$el.html(renderedContent);
      });
      return this;
    }


  });
  // Our module now returns our view
  return MitarbeiterListView;
});
```

Underscore template:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='mitarbeiter-anzeigen'>
    <% _.each( rc.mitarbeiter, function(mitarbeiter){ %>
        <div>test</div>
        <div><%= mitarbeiter.vorname %></div>

    <% }); %>   
</script>
```

The console.log(self.collection.toJSON()) logs the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your template you have:

```
<% _.each( rc.mitarbeiter, function(mitarbeiter){ %>
```

Where did that **rc** come from?

Here's what you code should look like inside your controller:

```
self.template({ "mitarbeiters": self.collection.toJSON() });
```

And then inside your template:

```
<% _.each( mitarbeiters, function(mitarbeiter){ %>
```

Comment: thx u saved my day :-) the rc comes from  _.templateSettings.variable = "rc";

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
///UPDATED underscore template:////

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='mitarbeiter-anzeigen'>
    <% _.each(rc.mitarbeiters, function(mitarbeiters){ %>
        <div><%= mitarbeiters.vorname %></div>

    <% }); %>
```

////UPDATED View:///////

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/mitarbeiter',
  'text!/aquilamus/templates/mitarbeiter/mitarbeiter.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, MitarbeiterCollection, MitarbeiterTemplate){



 var MitarbeiterListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#container"),
    initialize: function(){
      this.collection = new MitarbeiterCollection;

      var newtemplate = MitarbeiterTemplate;
       _.templateSettings.variable = "rc";
      this.template = _.template($(newtemplate).html());
    },
    render: function(){
      var self = this;

      // show some loading message
      this.$el.html('Loading');

      // fetch, when that is done, replace 'Loading' with content
      this.collection.fetch().done(function(){
          console.log(self.collection.toJSON());
          var renderedContent = self.template({ "mitarbeiters": self.collection.toJSON() });

          self.$el.html(renderedContent);
      });
      return this;
    }


  });
  // Our module now returns our view
  return MitarbeiterListView;
});
```